# Type conversion with default fallback value

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

In PostgreSQL (8.4), I'm trying to convert a string parameter into a date within a SQL query, falling back to `now()` when the string is not a valid date (or empty).

In "pseudo-SQL", this would be something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ? is not a valid date THEN now()::DATE ELSE CAST(? AS DATE) END;
```

I've tried to simplify the problem to detect an empty string using these two queries:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ?='' THEN now()::DATE ELSE CAST(? AS DATE) END;
SELECT DATE(CASE WHEN ?='' THEN now() ELSE ?  END);
```

For example, if the parameter is `''`, this is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ''='' THEN now()::DATE ELSE CAST('' AS DATE) END;
SELECT DATE(CASE WHEN ''='' THEN now() ELSE ''  END);
```

Both fail with `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""`
It makes sense, but it implies that the `ELSE` block is evaluated (or at least that its types are resolved) whether or not the `CASE` condition is true. The following works, but what I'd like the `CASE` (or similar) condition to handle, is precisely the case when it's not a valid date.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '2011-12-01'='' THEN now()::DATE ELSE CAST('2011-12-01' AS DATE) END;
```

The closest I got to a working solution is this:

```
SELECT DATE(COALESCE(NULLIF(?, '')::timestamptz, now()));
```

In this case, if the parameter is `''`, it returns the current date, otherwise, it returns the date passed in the string parameter (provided it can be turned into a valid date).

What I would like is to go a step further and make anything that cannot be turned into a `DATE` use the current date. I guess this could be done using a custom PL/pgSQL function that would [trap this error](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), but can this be done without such a function, in "plain" SQL (or at least using the existing PostgreSQL functions)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't handle [SQL exceptions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html) within an SQL statement like you can [from within PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

You must write a custom function as you suggest, for example:

```
create function is_valid_date(text) returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
  return case when $1::date is null then false else true end;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;$$;
```

test:

```
with w as (select 'asdsad'::text dt1, '2011-12-01'::text dt2, null::text dt3)
select case when is_valid_date(dt1) then dt1::date else current_date end d1,
       case when is_valid_date(dt2) then dt2::date else current_date end d2,
       case when is_valid_date(dt3) then dt3::date else current_date end d3
from w;

     d1     |     d2     |     d3
------------+------------+------------
 2011-12-06 | 2011-12-01 | 2011-12-06
```

Comment: credit to [this](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2006-04/msg00305.php) mailing list post